# I want to provide a file input to python file through terminal, but through routing using '<' in linux

Tags: python, linux, file, input, routes

I have a program that could establish a connection with a listener, similar to netcat. I want to develop it such that it could take a file as input and send it to the recipient.

```
sudo python3 my_program.py < input_file
```

Any ideas on how to take an input _file in this way, through the terminal? Any help is appreciated. Forgive me if the idea isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read from stdin:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    input_data = sys.stdin.read()
    print(input_data)
```

From here you should be able to figure out how to send `input_data` to "the recipient"